# Generate separate css file for each entrypoint in Vite

Tags: css, vite, rollup, postcss

So currently I have my library split as 2 entrypoints, so in Vite config I'm doing this:

```
build: {
    lib: {
      entry: [resolve(__dirname, 'src/entry1.ts'), resolve(__dirname, 'src/entry2.ts')],
      name: 'LibraryName',
      fileName: '[name]',
    },
  },
```

This causes Vite to generate 2 output files - `entry1.js` and `entry2.js`, but only single css file - `style.css`

How can I make Vite generate `entry1.css` and `entry2.css` for each entrypoint?

Comment: Im having a similar issue, following yours too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74826351/configuring-vanilla-ts-vite-project-to-keep-css-files-separated

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but this might be a solution for someone out there:

The fix is to set `build.cssCodeSplit` to `true`

For example:

```
build: {
    cssCodeSplit: true, // <-- this will generate at least one css file per entry point.
    lib: {
      entry: [resolve(__dirname, 'src/entry1.ts'), resolve(__dirname, 'src/entry2.ts')],
      name: 'LibraryName',
      fileName: '[name]',
    },
  },
```