# Configuring Vanilla TS Vite project to keep CSS files separated

Tags: css, split, bundle, vite

I am trying to set up a basic (css) library with vanilla TS and Vite 4.

I want to have a main js and css file at the top level so you can import the whole thing in one go. I also want to have component level imports where you can chose to just import the components js + css. The combined css and JS files are working fine; and the individual component JS file is working fine too.

Currently I'm running into the problem where I can't seem to keep an isolated version of the CSS files next to the JS files after bundling. My build is currently creating :

I've gone over the docs of both Vite and Rollup but I can't seem to figure out how to do the same to my CSS as I'm doing to my JS.

```
dist
--components
----button
------button.js
--main.css
--main.js

My preferred output would be:

dist
--components
----button
------button.js
------button.css
--main.css
--main.js

In my `main.ts` I'm importing:
```

```
import './style.scss'
import './tokens.scss'
import './components/button/button.scss'
```

```
vite.config.js
```

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    cssCodeSplit: false,
      manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: () => 'main[extname]',
      }
    },
    lib: {
      formats: ['es'],
      entry: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.ts'),
        button: resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/button/button.ts')
      },
      name: 'CSSFramework',
      fileName: (_, fileName) => fileName === 'main' ? '[name].js' : 'components/[name]/[name].js',
    },
  },
});
```

Thanks in advance !